# Zurb Foundation: media query for $column-gutter (Grid)

Tags: media-queries, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

In the Foundation framework, there is a variable called `$column-gutter`, which controls the space between columns in the grid. Is it possible to have a different value for `$column-gutter` dependent on the media-query state? I'd love to have wider column-gutters for my desktop-users and a smaller value for mobile.

Since you can't target variable values inside media-querys in SASS, I cannot think of any easy way, but maybe you have a different solution.
As kind of a workaround, I tried targeting my divs via media-query and overwriting the padding-attributes, like so:

```
@media #{$small} { // This is for desktop
  .l-header, .l-menu, .l-submenu, .l-main, .l-footer {
    padding-left: 3em;
    padding-right: 3em;
  }
}
```

But it's not really a nice solution since then I cannot maximize a nested grid-element inside another grid-element (because the padding of the parent div). Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Overwriting what foundation have is the right thing as well as doing it through media queries. What is your concern about not maximizing the nested grid? Do you want to remove the padding on the parent div and only have padding on the children div?

Comment: It turned out that the layout structure was not right for the project. At first I wanted to set the whole site apart from the background of the browser (with shadowed-border and stuff like that), but I found out that it was totally superfluous, because there was no reason for doing that. So I matched the background with the site content and there was no need for extra padding anymore. The padding was only necessary on small screens, so no need to change it. Maybe I had to overcome my fixed-size habits while designing responsive. :)